# how to get next value in array loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having this array:

```
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($test as $index => $value){
   echo $value . $next;
   // how to get the next one after the $value ??
}
```

so my display should be like:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
..
..
```

how can i get the next value in the loop of foreach ?

Comment: you have a lot of valid answers. you might consider accepting one. Also upvoting is a nice thing to do. you don't have to bake a cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it goes below, but remember that your foreach will print only 6 on the last round :)

```
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($test as $index => $value){
   echo $value . $test[$index+1];
}
```

Comment: And it will generate `undefined offset` in the last one.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I said about the last round. But it was for other purposes I suppose, so yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You could remember the last value and work that way:

```
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$last = null;
foreach($test as $index => $next){
  if(!is_null($last)) {
    echo $last . $next;
  }
  $last = $next;
}
```

Works even if your index is not numeric i.e. if it is like:

```
array(
'Peter' => 'Jackson',
'Steve' => 'McQueen',
'Paul' => 'McCartney',
'April' => 'Ludgate'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($test as $index => $value){
   if(end($test) == $test[$index+1]) {  
   echo $value . $test[$index+1];
   break;
  }
  else {
 echo $value . $test[$index+1];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

foreach($test as $value)
{
   echo $value;

   // We have advanced our array pointer. So next is already current
   $next = current($test);

   // If there is no next, it will return FALSE
   if($next)
      echo ' '.$next.'<br />';

   // Advance array pointer by one
   next($test);
}
?>
```

Output

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$len = count($test);
foreach($test as $index => $value){
    if($test[$index+1] != ''  && $test[$index] != '')
       echo $value . $test[$index+1].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: `$test = array(1,2,3,4,6,5,6);`

Comment: Sorry for that.See My Edit once

Comment: `$test = array(1,2,3,4, 6, '', 5,6);`

Comment: In `foreach` how can you get the empty value..??